# How to flush/invalidate cache entries pointing to kernel space memory addresses allocated with kmalloc

Tags: linux, caching, memory-management, linux-device-driver

I' developing a DMA driver for Linux/AMD64. For this purpose I need to flush and invalidate any entry in the CPU cache memories referencing addresses in memory buffers allocated with kmalloc. I thought initially that flush_kernel_vmap_range could do the job but it doesn't seem to have any effect and I only found empty flush_kernel_vmap_range definition in the Linux kernel source code. All other kernel methods to flush/invalidate cache entries are related to userspace memory.

Could someone help me, please, to find a way to flush/invalidate kernel memory?

flush_kernel_vmap_range(...)

The DMA device (located on a PCIe extension card) doesn't always see the correct content of the memory buffers as initialized by the CPU.

Comment: Have a look at the DMA mapping guide: [DMA-API-HOWTO.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt) in the kernel source code. Using this will take care of the cache flushing for you.